# Fatal error while building CiviCRM breadcrumb

Tags: error, drupal-9

I'm running against a fatal error on an number of CiviCRM pages (stacktrace below). There seems to be a problem with a url that is passed to Drupal\Core\Url::fromUserInput() when building the CiviCRM breadcrumb.

My setup:
Drupal 9.1.5 (multilingual nl and fr)
CiviCRM 5.35.0

Any ideas?

Thanks.

UPDATE: I've updated the stacktrace in response of the answer of Demerit. I've switched to core Bartik theme instead of my custom theme and experience the same error.

```
Er is onverwacht een fout opgetreden. Probeer het later nog eens.

InvalidArgumentException: The user-entered string 'https://nl.example.be.lndo.site/civicrm?reset=1' must begin with a '/', '?', or '#'. in Drupal\Core\Url::fromUserInput() (line 213 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Url.php).

Drupal\civicrm\CivicrmBreadcrumbBuilder->build(Object) (Line: 83)
Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\BreadcrumbManager->build(Object) (Line: 72)
Drupal\system\Plugin\Block\SystemBreadcrumbBlock->build() (Line: 171)
Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder::preRender(Array)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 101)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doTrustedCallback(Array, Array, 'Render #pre_render callbacks must be methods of a class that implements \Drupal\Core\Security\TrustedCallbackInterface or be an anonymous function. The callback was %s. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725', 'exception', 'Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderCallbackInterface') (Line: 781)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doCallback('#pre_render', Array, Array) (Line: 372)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) (Line: 444)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 200)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 450)
Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object, Array, 'html', NULL, 1) (Line: 90)
__TwigTemplate_7936d95d2109e2f3d9c3238b3a2874dfc12656eb43b3c81bb3249b679af13b6d->doDisplay(Array, Array) (Line: 405)
Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array) (Line: 378)
Twig\Template->display(Array) (Line: 390)
Twig\Template->render(Array) (Line: 65)
twig_render_template('core/themes/bartik/templates/page.html.twig', Array) (Line: 384)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('page', Array) (Line: 431)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 200)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 450)
Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object, Array, 'html', NULL, 1) (Line: 86)
__TwigTemplate_7a63433aced4475eeba9239a5c5c71c161379c0b5254aa839ee30a407195e9cd->doDisplay(Array, Array) (Line: 405)
Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array) (Line: 378)
Twig\Template->display(Array) (Line: 390)
Twig\Template->render(Array) (Line: 65)
twig_render_template('core/themes/bartik/templates/classy/layout/html.html.twig', Array) (Line: 384)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('html', Array) (Line: 431)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 200)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 162)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}() (Line: 573)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 163)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 142)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch(Object, 'kernel.view') (Line: 163)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 80)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 706)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Comment: This part is strange `Drupal\civicrm\CivicrmBreadcrumbBuilder->build(Object) (Line: 83)` because there is no line 83 in that file (src/CivicrmBreadcrumbBuilder.php). Do you have any customizations?

Comment: This is strange indeed. I'm using a fresh CiviCRM install with no customizations. The build function is line 59 of src/CivicrmBreadcrumbBuilder.

Comment: Ok, another clue then is `http://d9.example.be.lndo.site:/bin/civicrm?reset=1` is a very strange looking url. I'd double-check your settings in civicrm.settings.php and at civicrm/admin/setting/path and civicrm/admin/setting/url.

Comment: True, the strange looking path went away by resetting paths. The problem continues though and drupal complains about a valid URL (see updated stacktrace).  Seems like drupal does not expect the CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL is part of the url that is passed to the function.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your custom theme:

wig_render_template('themes/custom/b4_piosite/templates/page.html.twig', Array) (Line: 384)

It's doing something that this doesn't like:

Render #pre_render callbacks must be methods of a class that implements \Drupal\Core\Security\TrustedCallbackInterface or be an anonymous function. The callback was %s. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. I've switched back to core Bartik and still experience the error. I've updated the stacktrace in my original post.